# equivariant map $\mathbb{CP}^1 \to \mathbb{CP}^2:$ where does it send the boundary

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry, surfaces

Start from a map $\mathbb{CP}^1 \ni (u:v) \mapsto (x:y:z) \in \mathbb{CP}^2$ given by
$$ x = au^2, \quad y = av^2, \quad z = uv,$$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a parameter.
The image of the map is the conic
$$ xy - a^2z^2=0,$$
which is real under $(x:y:z) \mapsto (\overline{y}:\overline{x}:\overline{z}).$

To make the map equivariant, we choose to act on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ with the involution
$$ \Omega:(u:v) \mapsto (\overline{v}:\overline{u}).$$

The statement I want to prove or disprove is that we obtain a map from the disk to $\mathbb{CP}^2$ (and this is OK) *with boundary on $\mathbb{RP}^2.$*

---

I'm not fully convinced that the boundary is on $\mathbb{RP}^2:$ since the equation reduces by one the number of complex variables, and then reality is imposed, I would expect the boundary to be mapped to $\mathbb{RP}^1.$

In other terms, calling $C=\left\{ (x:y:z) \in \mathbb{CP}^2 \left| xy = a^2z^2 \right. \right\}$ the boundary should go to $L,$ where $L=\left\{ x \in C \left| \Omega(x)=x \right.\right\}$ is topologically $\mathbb{RP}^1.$

Comment: What makes you think so? Since $\alpha$ is only one real parameter, it cannot possibly describe all points of $\mathbb R^2$, much less $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: I modified the question in order to add some context

Comment: Should that be $xy-a^2z^2=0$, i.e. $z$ squared? $b$ would be $\frac1a$, right? I see how you map the unit disk to that conic, the boundary of which is a circle that you can parametrize by $\alpha\in[0,2\pi)$ as you did. I see how you embed it into $\mathbb{CP}^2$ but fail to see where $\mathbb{RP}^2$ enters the scene. Particularly since your definition of being real is not the common one here. But your language is quite a bit from what I'm used to, particularly those real-ness definitions, so I might simply be missing the point here.

Comment: Right. Reality means that it is invariant under that involution (it also invariant under standard complex conjugation). But still, the claim is that the image of the boundary is (perhaps homeomorphic to) the standard $\mathbb{RP}^2,$ which I can't see too.

Comment: The boundary (of the disk) still looks one-dimensional to me, no matter how I look. Its image can be considered *a subset of* $\mathbb{RP}^2$ (due to the three component real vector structure), but is essentially just a single topological circle embedded into the plane. I see a trivial homeomorphism to $\mathbb{RP}^1$ and an embedding of that into a perhaps slighty strange coordinatization of $\mathbb{RP}^2$, but that doesn't mean I can parametrize $\mathbb{RP}^2$ as a whole. All this is assuming $a$ resp. $b$ remain fixed; if they are to be a second parameter, everything changes.

Comment: yes, $a$ and $b$ remain fixed. Can you expand on the fact that the boundary is mapped into a subset of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ (perhaps this is the meaning of this whole matter)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12773/discussion-between-mvg-and-jj-p)